# Custom Control x:class Problems and Animation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I am trying to create a Menu Custom Control that contains some Animations to make things look a little more "Fluid". This is where I am running into Problems, I would like to have the Width of my Custom Control be driven by a animation to emulate the expanding of the menu. I can achieve this by using Triggers in the Template but using this method I can't seem to find a way to bind the "to", I had read that this isn't allowed because of Thread Safety so I figured I would just use the "Click" event and do the Animation in the Code Behind.

Well when I tried to add my class to the Resource Dictionary I end up getting a bunch of errors saying *'"DefaultStyleKeyProperty" does not exist in the current context'* in the Class file. I need to add my class to the Resource Dictionary in order to be able to get to any of the UI Objects. So I am a little stuck on how to achieve this, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Here is what I have so far:

### NavMenu.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="Happ.UI.Controls.NavMenu"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Happ.UI.Controls">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:NavMenu}">
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Background="Yellow" Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:NavMenu}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="btnMenu" 
                                      Margin="10" Padding="4" Background="Transparent"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:NavMenu}}, Path=IsExpanded}" />
                        </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

### NavMenu.cs

```
namespace Happ.UI.Controls {

    public partial class NavMenu : Menu {

        static NavMenu() {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata( typeof( NavMenu ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( typeof( NavMenu ) ) );
        }

        public bool IsExpanded {
            get {
                return (bool)GetValue( IsExpandedProperty );
            }
            set {
                TimeSpan tsTime = new TimeSpan( 0, 0, 0, 0, 500 );
                DoubleAnimation mnuAnim = new DoubleAnimation( MinWidth, tsTime );
                btnMenu.BeginAnimation( Width, mnuAnim );
                SetValue( IsExpandedProperty, value );
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register( "IsExpanded", typeof( bool ), typeof( NavMenu ), new PropertyMetadata( true ) );
        }
    }
}
```

### Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Happ.UI.Controls">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Happ.UI.Controls;component/Templates/NavMenu.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>



</ResourceDictionary>
```

I tried adding the xClass into the Generic.xaml also with no luck, when I did that I received another additional error: "Partial declarations of 'NavMenu' must no specify different base classes".

### Edit

---

I knew there had to be a better way of doing this, using the Interactivity Library. What I ended up doing is creating a new class specifically for the Animations. Then I can attach the new TriggerAction to my Control, one thing that I did figure out is I need to have a ListContainer for the target animation element. This is because there is no way to achieve the animation from 0 to "Auto", the Panel provides a way to get the children and calculate the "Auto" width in code. Here are my updates:

### NavMenu.cs

```
namespace Happ.UI.Controls {

    public class NavMenu : Menu {

        static NavMenu() {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata( typeof( NavMenu ), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( typeof( NavMenu ) ) );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Flag to Tell if the Menu is Expanded
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsExpanded {
            get {
                return (bool)GetValue( IsExpandedProperty );
            }
            set {
                SetValue( IsExpandedProperty, value );
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register( "IsExpanded", typeof( bool ), typeof( NavMenu ), new PropertyMetadata( true ) );
    }
}
```

### NavMenu.Animations.cs

```
namespace Happ.UI.Controls {

    public class NavMenuAnimations : System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerAction<UIElement> {

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the Target Element for the Animation
        /// </summary>
        public Panel TargetPanel {
            get {
                return (Panel)GetValue( TargetPanelProperty );
            }
            set {
                SetValue( TargetPanelProperty, value );
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetPanelProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register( "TargetPanel", typeof( Panel ), typeof( NavMenuAnimations ),
            new PropertyMetadata( null ) );

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the Target Element for the Animation
        /// </summary>
        public double Seconds {
            get {
                return (double)GetValue( SecondsProperty );
            }
            set {
                SetValue( SecondsProperty, value );
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register( "Seconds", typeof( double ), typeof( NavMenuAnimations ),
            new PropertyMetadata( (double)0.5 ) );

        /// <summary>
        /// This is the Main Animation Method that is called each time the Trigger occurs
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parameter"></param>
        protected override void Invoke( object parameter ) {
            double maxWidth = 0;

            //Make sure that we have a Target Element
            if( TargetPanel == null ) {
                throw new Exception( "No Target Element specified for the animation. (NavMenu Animations)" );
            }

            //Make sure the Min Width and Height are Set
            TargetPanel.MinWidth = ( Width > 0 ) ? Width : TargetPanel.MinWidth;


            //Check if the MaxWidth has been set
            if( Double.IsInfinity( TargetPanel.MaxWidth ) ) {

                //Loop through the Children and Get Width
                foreach( UIElement elem in TargetPanel.Children ) {

                    //Update the Max Width of the Panel
                    maxWidth += elem.RenderSize.Width;
                }

                //Check if we found a MaxWidth. if not return
                if( maxWidth == 0 )
                    return;

                //Assign the new MaxWidth
                TargetPanel.MaxWidth = maxWidth;
            }

            //Check if Width is at Minumum (Shrunk)
            if( TargetPanel.Width == TargetPanel.MinWidth ) {

                TargetPanel.BeginAnimation( FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, new DoubleAnimation( TargetPanel.MaxWidth, TimeSpan.FromSeconds( Seconds ) ) );
            }
            else {

                TargetPanel.BeginAnimation( FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, new DoubleAnimation( TargetPanel.MinWidth, TimeSpan.FromSeconds( Seconds ) ) );
            }


        }

    }
}
```

### NavMenuTemplate.xaml

---

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Happ.UI.Controls">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:NavMenu}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="navMenu" Orientation="Vertical">

                    </StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:NavMenu}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="Transparent"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Viewbox Grid.Row="0"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                     Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:NavMenu}}, Path=IconSize}"
                                     Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:NavMenu}}, Path=IconSize}">
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="btnMenu" Grid.Row="0" 
                                              Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:NavMenu}}, Path=MenuIcon}"
                                              Background="Transparent"
                                              Padding="0"
                                              IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:NavMenu}}, Path=IsExpanded}">
                                </ToggleButton>
                            </Viewbox>
                            <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="1" MinWidth="50">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger SourceName="btnMenu" EventName="Click" >
                                        <local:NavMenuAnimations TargetPanel="{Binding ElementName=navMenu}"  Technique="ExpandWidth" />
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </ItemsPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This is getting very close to what I need, I only have one problem remaining. Because of the orientation of my Elements I needed to define a ItemsPanelTemplate which is the Element that I need to Animate. The problem is however I can not figure out how to locate the "navMenu" element. I know this is simply a Context issue I just don't know how to get to the right place. I have tried using the RelativeParent={RelativeParent TemplatedParent} but I can not use the assigned name with it. Can anyone tell me how I can pass a reference to the ItemsPanelTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

Why is the `NavMenu` defined as `partial` in the first place? This should only be class wihout any XAML except for the default template that you defined in your NavMenu.xaml file. You should *not* have any NavMenu.xaml.cs file.

Also your `IsExpanded` CLR wrapper should *only* set the value of the dependency property.

To get a reference to the "btnMenu" `ToggleButton` that is defined in the template of the custom control you should override the `OnApplyTemplate` method:

```
public class NavMenu : Menu
{
    static NavMenu()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(NavMenu), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(NavMenu)));
    }

    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(IsExpandedProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsExpandedProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("IsExpanded", typeof(bool), typeof(NavMenu), new PropertyMetadata(true));

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton btnMenu = Template.FindName("btnMenu", this) as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton;
        TimeSpan tsTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500);
        DoubleAnimation mnuAnim = new DoubleAnimation(0.0, MinWidth, tsTime);
        btnMenu.BeginAnimation(WidthProperty, mnuAnim);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a NavMenu.cs.xaml I only have a NavMenu.xaml I guess I should of named it NavMenuTemplate.xaml. The Partial that I had in my class was from trying to set the x:class of the ResourceDictionary when I was trying to get the Reference. And the reason that I had the Animation in the IsExtended property is I was trying to find a way to get the Mouse Click.

Comment: You should still override the OnApplyTemplate method as I suggested. Did you try this?

Comment: I did try the OnApplyTemplate and that got me very close to what I needed but not quite. I did update my question to reflect what I did come up with however there is still one minor problem with the Template and the Trigger.